# Estructura de un servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Soy nuevo en esto y no termino de entender la estructura de un Servlet al parecer solo consta de 3 métodos doGet,doPost y processRequest no ?  pero en que momento se ejecuta cada uno ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un servlet es un objeto en ejecución en un servidor que se encarga de interceptar peticiones enviadas por un cliente y generar una respuesta. El tipo de servlet más popular es `HttpServlet` que se encarga de los métodos HTTP como GET y POST, entre otros.

En Java EE estos servlets se configuran para escuchar en cierta URL o específicamente en un patrón de URL, ya sea desde el archivo de configuración `web.xml` o con la anotación `@WebServlet`.

Un servlet es creado por un servlet container, la primera vez que es requerido o durante la inicialización y se mantendrá en memoria durante toda la ejecución de la aplicación. Esa misma instancia será reutilizada para cada petición con una URL que coincida con el patrón URL del servlet.

Por ejemplo el patrón `/sitio/*`, coincide con las siguientes URLs:

- `http://server.com/server/sitio/entrada`
- `http://server.com/server/sitio/orden?id=2`
- `http://server.com/server/sitio`

**¿Cómo se ejecutan los métodos?**

Dependiendo del tipo de petición que envíe el cliente el servlet puede ejecutar el método `doGet()` (click en un link, acceder a una URL desde la barra de direcciones) o `doPost()` (login, envío de formulario). Para acceder a los datos de la petición se usa el objeto `HttpServletRequest` y para enviar la respuesta el objeto `HttpSevletResponse`.

Solo uno de estos métodos es necesario para que un servlet cumpla su tarea, pero varios pueden ser escritos en caso de que se requieran.

Answer (score 0):

En Java EE, existe la interfaz [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) que define cómo debe definirse un servlet. Cualquier clase que implemente esta interfaz y se configure como `@WebServlet` en el código o vía XML:

```
<servlet-config>
    <servlet-name>MiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>paquete.donde.esta.la.ClaseServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet-config>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-url>/una/url</servlet-url>
</servlet-mapping>
```

La interfaz posee varios métodos, de los cuales los siguientes son los principales, ordenados de acuerdo al ciclo de vida del Servlet (los otros métodos no son tan relevantes pero igual se deben implementar):

- `init(ServletConfig config)`: Método invocado luego de crear el Servlet. Permite brindar parámetros de configuración luego de iniciar el Servlet. Estos parámetros pueden ser utilizados para iniciar recursos, tal como abrir una conexión a base de datos o indicar una carpeta donde se encontrarán archivos que necesitan procesarse.
- `service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)`: Método que permite atender una petición hecha al servidor. Requiere como parámetros información sobre la petición, que se encuentra en `ServletRequest`, y los elementos que se escribirán como parte de la respuesta, que se encuentra en `ServletResponse`.
- `destroy()`: Método que se ejecuta previo a la eliminación del Servlet. Este método debe contener código para liberar cualquier recurso utilizado por la instancia del servlet. Al decir que el servlet se *"elimina"* en realidad se deja de utilizar para atender peticiones, y luego la memoria que ocupa puede ser reclamada por el Garbage Collector.

Para facilitar el desarrollo de los servlets, se proveen dos clases que ya implementan esta interfaz y permiten a los desarrolladores concentrarse en trabajo más puntual.

La primera clase es [`GenericServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html). Esta clase abstracta implementa la interfaz `Servlet` y provee funcionalidad básica para casi todos los métodos, con excepción del método `service`.

La segunda clase es [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html). Esta clase abstracta extiende de `GenericServlet` e implementa el método `service`. Además, provee un método `service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)` que facilita la ejecución de métodos asociados a los verbos HTTP. Esta clase también provee los métodos `doGet`, `doPost` y otros también importantes: `doPut`, `doDelete`, `doHead`, `doOptions`, `doTrace`, para soportar otros verbos HTTP. En la implementación de este método `service` existe el siguiente fragmento de código que te explica cuándo se ejecuta cada método `doXxx` (obtenido del código de `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` en su versión 3.1.0):

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String method = req.getMethod();
    //si el método es GET
    if (method.equals(METHOD_GET)) {
        long lastModified = getLastModified(req);
        if (lastModified == -1) {
            // servlet doesn't support if-modified-since, no reason
            // to go through further expensive logic
            doGet(req, resp);
        } else {
            long ifModifiedSince = req.getDateHeader(HEADER_IFMODSINCE);
            if (ifModifiedSince < lastModified) {
                // If the servlet mod time is later, call doGet()
                // Round down to the nearest second for a proper compare
                // A ifModifiedSince of -1 will always be less
                maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
                doGet(req, resp);
            } else {
                resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
            }
        }
    //si el método es HEAD
    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_HEAD)) {
        long lastModified = getLastModified(req);
        maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
        doHead(req, resp);
    //si el método es POST
    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_POST)) {
        doPost(req, resp);
    //si el método es PUT
    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_PUT)) {
        doPut(req, resp);
    //si el método es DELETE
    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_DELETE)) {
        doDelete(req, resp);
    //si el método es OPTIONS
    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_OPTIONS)) {
        doOptions(req,resp);
    //si el método es TRACE
    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_TRACE)) {
        doTrace(req,resp);
    //si el método es desconocido, no lo soporta
    } else {
        //
        // Note that this means NO servlet supports whatever
        // method was requested, anywhere on this server.
        //

        String errMsg = lStrings.getString("http.method_not_implemented");
        Object[] errArgs = new Object[1];
        errArgs[0] = method;
        errMsg = MessageFormat.format(errMsg, errArgs);

        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, errMsg);
    }
}
```

El motivo de que `HttpServlet` sea una clase abstracta es para que no puedas configurar un servlet directamente como `HttpServlet` y exija al desarrollador que extienda dicha clase.

---

> al parecer solo consta de 3 métodos doGet,doPost y processRequest

Tal como puedes ver, ninguno de esos métodos forma parte de `Servlet`. Los métodos `doGet` y `doPost` son los métodos provistos para atender las peticiones tipo GET y POST. Los IDEs generan el código relevante para estos métodos porque cuando surgieron las aplicaciones Web, los navegadores solo podían enviar peticiones de tipo GET y POST, por ende el soporte a los otros métodos no era necesario. El método `processRequest` es un método que provee el IDE asumiendo que procesarás las peticiones GET y POST de la misma manera, lo cual es **INCORRECTO**. El método GET debe ser utilizado para pre procesar la vista y/u obtener información. El método POST debe ser utilizado para procesar información y generar una vista o redirigir a una nueva vista.